# Waiting for AJAX request to finish?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that is confusing me at the moment. I am using ajax to get some ID's from a website. Once it's complete I want to store the ID's in a variable for further processing. I have my code laid out like this:

```
var ids;

function get_ids() { ... Get the ID's from the site and store them in the global variable ids ... }

get_ids();
alert(ids.length);
```

As you can see ids will always be 0 because the script will continue to run before the ajax request in get_ids has had a chance to respond.

What's the best way to what I'm trying to do? I want to wait until get_ids has finished.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make `get_ids` take a callback parameter and call it when it receives a response.

For example:

```
function get_ids(callback) {
    ...
        response: function(data) {
            ...
            callback(data);
        }
    ...
}

get_ids(function(ids) { 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your AJAX framework, but pretty much any framework will allow you to specify a function to run when the AJAX request is complete.  In JQuery:

```
function get_ids_complete() {
    alert(ids.length);
}

function get_ids() {
    $.get('/ids', function (data) {
        // do something with the data
        get_ids_complete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using plain old javasript, you can call a function to run after the AJAX has completed like so:

```
ajaxCall.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (ajaxCall.readyState==4 && ajaxCall.status==200)
    {
     //do your ID stuff here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using synchronous AJAX in situations like that; it's a blocking call, which I ordinarily avoid, but I don't see an alternative.

See [Synchronous AJAX](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets%3a_Synchronous_AJAX)

Comment: Link appears to be down